# how to fetch data from html controls in view to controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i have some pages written in html and all the controls are in html like for text box it is  and i cant change these control to @html.text.
but i have to fetch data from  and do some logic on data in controller.can somebody tell me how to fetch data ?
this is html code in my view written in html

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <label class="label">Customer Name</label>
                                <select class="browser-default" name="Customername">
                                    <option value="Customer Name1">Customer Name1</option>
                                    <option>Customer Name2</option>
                                    <option>Customer Name3</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="pull-left"><a href="#" class="newCustomer">New Customer</a></div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <label class="label">Job Referene</label>
                                <select class="browser-default" name="jobreference">
                                    <option>Job Referene</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <label class="label">Quantity</label>
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" />
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <label class="label">Browser Select</label>
                                <select class="browser-default">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                </select>
```

i want to get data in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

If the html controls have a name you can use FormCollection like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var value = formCollection["nameOfControl"];
        //do stuff
        return View();
    }
}
```

Beware though; this is - in general - not a good approach.

Comment: also see: https://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/get-forms-post-values-in-asp-net-mvc-with-formcollection/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a name attribute on each of your html controls in the view page to access its value in the controller

In your view

```
<input type ="text" name"Textbox1" value="TestValue" />
```

In your Controller

```
public ActionResult Test(string Textbox1)
{
   // Do your code manipulation here
}
```

**Note: The name attribute must match the parameter name in the controller , you can have as many named parameters you want , or else you can use a single form collection to access the input fields.**

Comment: there are so many controls ...how can i use this way to get data?

Comment: use the formcollection - like I said in my answer - all controls will be pushed into the collection on post.

Comment: i used formcollection but i just got the name attribute of every control not the value that i fill in my controls.... :(

Comment: i want to fetch data which is filled by user in html controls

Comment: Is your controls inside a form tag ?
<form>
//Your Controls here 
</form>